# How do I replace the first three characters of a Java integer by 111?

Tags: java, replace, numbers, integer

I have an integer in java. How do I replace its’ first three numbers with 111(or any other number), for example turning 783729 into 111729?
Many thanks!

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this problem? Have you considered trying some math? Or converting the integer to a `String` applying the replacement and then parsing back to an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert it into a string and then replace the first three letters.

```
String s = String.valueOf(783729);
int i = Integer.parseInt(s.replace(s.substring(0, 3), "111"));
```

Comment: If inputs could be negative that would obviously need to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the integer to string replace the first three characters and convert it back to integer.kindly try to do it yourself. if you feel stuck during coding post your code along with the problem you face.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without converting to a string using simple arithmetic:

```
// Assumes that num is initially at least 999.
int replaceWith111(int num) {
  if (num < 1000) {
    return 111;
  }
  return 10 * replaceWith111(num / 10) + (num % 10) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if you just need to get this done you'd convert to `String` and do the substitution there.

However, just for fun, here's how you could do it using only `Math` functions and operators. Doesn't handle negative numbers - that's left as an exercise fo the reader :)

```
int s = 111;
int n = 783729;

int ds = (int)Math.ceil(Math.log10(s));
int dn = (int)Math.ceil(Math.log10(n));
int b = (int)Math.pow(10, dn-ds);
int sn = s * b + n % b;

System.out.println(sn);
```

Output:

```
111729
```